# Describing a number that is supposed change something relative to a certain value

Tags: grammar

I need to describe a parameter in a program and i am struggling with grammar. The parameter is called "delta" and is supposed to be an amount that changes a certain value.

So my trys are:

- The delta which to change the value by
- The delta of which to change the value by
- The delta by which to change the value

I can't figure out which is correct (if one of these is correct at all). At least they sound wrong to me.

Comment: Isn't this the _increment_?

Comment: Yes, increment if its positive, decrement if its negative or even offset as Marv Mills suggested. Actually the headline of this question could have been better because i wanted to know about the grammar of the above scentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I lean to your third, but with limited knowledge of your subject or context, my own personal usage would probably be something along this line:

*The delta, by which the value is changed.* or: *...by which to change the value.*

I shy away from the first two examples only because of my reluctance to wrap up a clause in a preposition.

Answer (score 1):

If the value is used in conjunction with the original value:
Offset?

If the value is used to actually change the other value by this amount:
Adjustment?